# Move-class does not get applied to remaining items in transition-group if other items got removed

Tags: css, vue.js, css-transitions

I got an item list where each item is put in a flex-box, displaying the list like a matrix (several rows and items per row). Using `<transition-group class="move">` I apply a simple move transition on the `<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">`

```
move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Now, this works perfectly when changing the order of the items or when adding new items; meaning all existing items move to their new place smoothly.

But: If I remove items from the list and some gaps occur, the existing items do NOT fill these gaps smoothly but jump to their new position without animation.

What's the reason for those existing items to behave differently, smoothly moving in their new position if a new item is put in between them but jump back without animation when the very same item is removed? How can I achieve a smooth move both ways?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Using the move transition, the -leave-active transition class must apply a `position: absolute` declaration, in order to take it out of the layout flow, so the siblings can -move in to place around it.